# Not able to install Operating System

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bios, sata, windows-installation

I had a problem day before yesterday that I accidentally formatted my hard disk and lost all my data. Now during re-installation of windows it shows that windows can't be installed and my hard disk is write-protected. It also says that 'ensure that the disk controller is enabled in the BIOS menu'. My hard disk was enabled IDE in BIOS which I also turned to AHCI and all the settings regarding the hard disk & SATA but then also it shows the same error and when I try to create new partitions it doesn't creates and shows 'cannot create partition. Error:0x80070017. Please anyone help me out to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Try restoring the BIOS to the default settings (usually that's a choice on the last page), and start over.

Comment: @sawdust I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: What procedure did not work?  You can't set the BIOS to defaults?

Comment: @sawdust No, no. I mean that I set the BIOS to defaults but then also it shows the same error.